# Why is Spring Boot handling a "404 Not Found" for entities differently?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I am wondering why Spring Boot is handling 404 Not Found differently.

**None existing path example**

I make a request on a none existing path with curl:

```
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=" http://localhost:8080/no/endpoint | python -m json.tool
* Adding handle: conn: 0x69aa30
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x69aa30) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to localhost port 8080 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /no/endpoint HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=
>
< HTTP/1.1 404
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=62B5B02F18842F3BD46BCE57F2EAB017;path=/;HttpOnly
< X-Application-Context: Rechnungsservice Gateway:dev
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: 0
< Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 11:59:19 GMT
<
{ [data not shown]
100   115    0   115    0     0    569      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   614
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/no/endpoint",
    "status": 404,
    "timestamp": 1487591959599
}
```

Same operation with a browser:
[image]

**And now I request an endpoint for an none existing entity:**

```
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=" http://localhost:8080/api/v1/settings/123 | python -m json.tool                                                                                                                    

* Adding handle: conn: 0x62aa40                                                                                       
* Adding handle: send: 0                                                                                              
* Adding handle: recv: 0                                                                                              
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1                                                                                 
* - Conn 0 (0x62aa40) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0                                                                      
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current                                       
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed                                         
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* About to connect() to localhost port 8
080 (#0)                                                                                                              
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...                                                                                               
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)                                                                   
> GET /api/v1/settings/123 HTTP/1.1                                                                                   
> User-Agent: curl/7.33.0                                                                                             
> Host: localhost:8080                                                                                                
> Accept: */*                                                                                                         
> Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMjM=                                                                           
>                                                                                                                     
< HTTP/1.1 404                                                                                                        
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=BCD5ADDA48EB03C235E6573A36860F7D;path=/;HttpOnly                                             
< X-Application-Context: Rechnungsservice Gateway:dev                                                                 
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff                                                                                     
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block                                                                                     
< Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate                                                       
< Pragma: no-cache                                                                                                    
< Expires: 0                                                                                                          
< Content-Length: 0                                                                                                   
< Date: Mon, 20 Feb 2017 12:05:29 GMT                                                                                 
<                                                                                                                     
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0                                        
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact                                                                         
No JSON object could be decoded
```

Same operation in browser:
[image]

So my question is: Why is Spring Boot only sending a simple 404 Status in case of the not found entity? I would like to see a nice message: Entity not found or something like this on my error page for text/html or a json error object in case of a json request... For the path example it is working like a charm out of the box...

I am using Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE.

**UPDATE:**
Sorry I forgot to say that I am using Spring Data Rest.
And here I debugged unti I found this code snippet:

```
class RepositoryEntityController ... {

public ResponseEntity<Resource<?>> getItemResource(...) {

Object domainObj = getItemResource(resourceInformation, id);

    if (domainObj == null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Resource<?>>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

}
```

In my opinion a request to a single entity that doesn't exists should throw a "NotFoundException", leading to a better response.

Answer (score 2):

The first request never reaches your Spring application, your WAR is not deployed at that location, so instead you get the generic 404 message from the web server (Tomcat perhaps).